# How to auto select value in mat-selects Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an array: `let options = ["NAMNE", "AGE"]`.

It is rendered in loop:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let option in options">
    <mat-select></mat-select>
</ng-container>
```

As result I get two `mat-selects`:

```
  Mat-select Mat-select
    Name        Age
```

How to toggle them if user choose instead 'Name' the `Age`:

```
Mat-select Mat-select
Age         Age
```

It should be:

```
Mat-select Mat-select
Age         Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following Code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let option in options">
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" placeholder="Mode">
    <mat-option value="domain">Domain</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="exact">Exact</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```